# Route redirecting to an external link caught in a loop in react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

From a react application i am calling an external link with react router as below

```
<PrivateRoute exact path='/a/b' component={() => { 
                        window.location = `https://externallink/a/b`; 
                        return null;
                    }}/>
```

The redirection is working but it is caught in a loop. It calls the external link indefinitely. How can I stop the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<PrivateRoute exact path='/a/b' component={() => { 
                        useEffect(()=>{
                        const redirectLink = `https://externallink/a/b`
                        window.location !== redirectLink 
                        && window.location = redirectLink
                        },[])
                        return null;
                    }}/>
```